# How to determine how a dll is ending up in my /bin (.NET)

Tags: .net, msbuild

I've got a solution with two projects, `A` and `B`. `A` references an external dll `C.dll` from an external `/lib` folder.

When I build `B`, `C.dll` is ending up in its `/bin` folder.

`B` does not reference `A` or `C.dll` (but `A` does reference `B`).

There is no mention (reference) to/of `C.dll` anywhere in project `B`, why is it in its `/bin`? How can I determine where its coming from?

Update: Using .NET 3.5

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that if you delete c.dll from B's bin it keeps turning up. Or is it just there from earlier?

Comment: Because that sounds a bit weird to me too.

Comment: no, its not left over. clean and build puts it back in. I know its something weird happening, never seen this behaviour before. Is there i way i can determine how MSBuild is deciding it needs copying in, like some verbose debug mode?

Comment: Are these projects in the same solution?  What is the startup project?

Comment: Yes, in the same project. No default startup, happens if i just build `B.csproj` from the command line with MSBuild

Comment: you can just look at the files -- they are all text I believe (eg B.csproj)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build your solution on the command line with MSBuild and increase the verbosity you can figure it out. You can just execute the following in a Visual Studio Command Prompt *(found in the Start Menu under Visual Studio)*.

```
msbuild.exe YourSolution.sln /flp:v=diag
```

This will create write the log file `msbuild.log` in the current directory. Then you can search for the file name and back track how it is being copied into that directory. If `v=diag` is too much info you can try `v=detailed`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the references in Solution Explorer?  Maybe there is a left over reference to it there.

Comment: yep, no references to it from `B`